# Can Ingress route requests based on ip?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have been with `K8s-ingress` well so far but I have a question.

Can `ingress` route requests based on **IP**?

I've already know that ingress do routing based on hosts like a.com, b.com... to each services and URI like path /a-service/*, /b-service/* to each services.

However, I'm curious with the idea that `Ingress` can route by **IP**? I'd like requests from my office(certain ip) to route a specific service for tests.

Does it make sense? and any idea for that?

Comment: Eww. Sorry about that. Could I delete it?

Comment: Do you need ip based routing only for testing or is there any other use case also ?

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande Only for testing now.

Answer (score 4):

If this is just for testing I would just whitelist the IP. You can read the docs about [nginx ingress annotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#whitelist-source-range)

> You can specify allowed client IP source ranges through the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range` annotation. The value is a comma separated list of [CIDRs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing), e.g. `10.0.0.0/24,172.10.0.1`.

Example yaml might look like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: whitelist
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "1.1.1.1/24"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: echoheaders
          servicePort: 80
```

Also it looks like you can do that in [Istio](https://istio.io/) (I did not tried it) in **kind** `ServiceRole` and `ServiceRoleBinding` for specifying detailed access control requirements. For this you would use `source.ip` property. It's explained on [Constraints and Properties](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/authorization/constraints-and-properties/)

Comment: I also came across this one, however, this is not what I want. Thank you though !

Comment: Why is this only *for testing*? It also may be used for production

Answer (score 0):

This is not part of the main Ingress abstraction as you noted, however many Ingress Controllers offer extra features through annotations or secondary CRDs. So in theory it could be added like that. I don't think any do routing like this though, so in practical terms, probably not available off the shelf.

Comment: Thank you ! I will search for it more and think of my structure again.

Comment: FWIW a few controllers do allow IP-based ACLs, but not routing. So you could use a hostname-based route specifically for testing and then ACL-restrict it your office. You may also want to look into the (very complex) world of Service Mesh tools as they sometimes offer more complex networking goop.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that idea. I've also searched for Istio but I'm quite new to k8s so I will adopt Istio later when I get used to k8s and need more complex network and other needs.

Answer (score 0):

As coderanger stated in his answer, ingress does not have it by default.

I'm not sure if IP based routing is the way to proceed, because how will you test/hit actual deployments/services from Office IP's when needed?

I think you can add a check to perform routing based on IP and header. For ex: you can pass a header `'redirect-to-test: true'`. So if you set this to false, you can still access the production services.

Comment: Let me try it out later. I decided to use a hostname-based route for that though.